# Symfony+Doctrine migrations problems

Tags: php, symfony1

I've got a strange problem with Symfony (with sfDoctrineGuardPlugin installed) and Doctrine migrations. What I've done till now:

- I've dropped database and created new one withou tables
- I've cleaned all model files
- I've cleared cache
- run symfony task "`doctrine:generate-migrations-db`"

After that, I think that should be not differences between database and migration's files.
Next I've run "`doctrine:generate-migrations-diff`" and got two new files with:

1. [File one](http://pastebin.com/p27CpWAT)
2. [File two](http://pastebin.com/F3aTdpCG)

That was strange for me couse I've expected no differences, but I've run "`doctrine:migrate --up`" two times for two migrations generated earlier. Migrations passed. And now, what makes me confused is fact that every run of "`doctrine:generate-migrations-diff`", generates exactly same differences like in two files that I've linked in this post.

Thanks for any suggestions,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

That's because `doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` works by comparing what's in your schema.yml file to your model classes.

You always need to run

```
symfony doctrine:build --all-classes
```

after you run symfony `doctrine:migrate`

Comment: Hi,
I'm not sure that migrations works as you sad. The description for this task is ":generate-migrations-diff           Generate migration classes by producing a diff between your old and new schema."

Comment: generate-migrations-diff compares the schema yml files with your existing models.